# Is there any reason why the continuum hypothesis cannot be taken as a postulate which may or may not be true?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I was reading through the Wikipedia article on the [Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) and I was unclear why it couldn't be handled like the Parallel Postulate of Euclid?

Is there any reason to believe that there must be an answer to this question?  If it turns out that the Continuum Hypothesis is undecidable would that not open up at least two different branches of mathematical systems: one system where the Continuum Hypothesis is true and one where it is false?

Would it be accurate to say that the Parallel Postulate of Euclid is undecidable since a logically consistent geometry can be built from assuming it is true or assuming it is false?

Sorry if these questions are dumb. I'm trying to get my head around the continuum hypothesis, decidability, and its relation to non-Euclidean Geometry systems if there is any relationship.

Comment: This is exactly how it is handled; but you should replace "undecidable" with "independent from the rest of ZFC axioms."

Comment: Thanks very much.  I wanted to make sure that I was understanding the concept correctly.  So, if it is independent, then it should be possible to have a ZFC+ set of axioms where the CH is assumed true and a ZFC- set of axioms where the CH is assumed false.

Comment: That's right...

Comment: There is no reason you can't treat CH or its negation as a postulate. But we don't in most practice because we don't have **any** intuition about it. Unlike The Axiom of Choice, where there is some intuition, even though the results of the choice sometimes seem mind-boggling, we really have no intuition for CH.

Comment: But I can imagine there would be interest in results like, "If CH is is true, then (some interesting result.)"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, there are results like this of interest to people who are in fields far removed from logic and foundations.

Comment: As one example I remember seeing, if CH is true, and you fix some well-order of $[0,1]$ with order type $\omega_1$, then each horizontal slice of that subset of $[0,1]^2$ is countable and therefore of Lebesgue measure 0, while each vertical slice is cocountable and therefore of Lebesgue measure 1.  (Thus giving an illustration of the requirement of measurability with respect to the product order in the statement of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, not just requiring both iterated integrals to be defined.)

Comment: Joerg Resag said in a german website that adding the axiom that CH is false to ZFC makes ZFC "richer" and therefore there are good reasons to do this. But adding the axiom that CH is true to ZFC is also possible. If ZFC is consistent , both choices lead to a consistent version of ZFC as well.

Comment: @Peter. Adding $\neg CH$  also makes ZFC  "poorer" in that some kinds of sets must be omitted, e.g. injections from $\Bbb R$ to $\omega_1$.